# Offline wireless data transfer

Tags: file-management, networking, bluetooth, wireless, nfc

**Requirements:** File transfer (images/videos) from a PC/Mac to Mobile devices (android and iOS) with NO INTERNET AND DATA services.

I looked into **Airdrop** for IOS however the challenges is it's only for IOS devices. I'm also aware about **NFC/Beam** but it looks like it only works on Android only (not sure)

**Snapdrop** looks cool, however it's internet dependent too.

The ideal working scenario is to have wifi hotspot or Airdrop-like functionality that works on both Android and IOS.

I also tested **Bluetooth File exchange** on Mac to my android phone, it works but it's snail slow. :(

Any ideas or tech recommendation I would need to look into is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the free version of [Syncios](https://www.syncios.com/features.html) to back up my Android phone.  I connect my phone to my Windows laptop with a USB cable and back up the data on the phone to folders on my laptop.  It also supports iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The only soft not based in cloud that I know is the opensource and multiplatform [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/).
The official app has not client for iOS but [Mobius sync](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mobiussync/id1539203216?ign-itscg=30200&ign-itsct=apps_box#?platform=iphone) is a client Syncthing compatible.